# Confused about pointers and values in Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm using the MASM Assembler.
Let's look at this short code (from a book I've been reading):

```
    .data
var1 BYTE 10h

.code
main proc
    mov esi,OFFSET byteVal
    mov al,[esi] ; AL = 10h
```

I didn't exactly understand how byteVal is translated to machine code - I know it's an identifier, a symbolic name. As I understand, at runtime byteVal is the memory **address** of the value 10h, right?
but the book says that these two instructions are the same:

```
mov al var1
mov al,[var1]
```

I don't understand why they do the same.

---

var1 = the address of 10h

[var1] = 10h

---

Isn't this true?
the book said that square brackets "dereference" the variable, yet it said that these two are the same.

and if var1 is the location in memory, what's the difference between it and using OFFSET var1 then ?
I mean, offset is the location in memory, isn't it?
and the book said: "The OFFSET operator returns the distance of a variable from the beginning of its enclosing
segment."
Why then the first variable's offset isn't zero, since it's the first variable in the segment? I just CANT figure it out. Probably I should switch a book...

Comment: I'm surprised if `mov al, var1` is actually accepted by MASM. Conventionally, it's either `mov esi, OFFSET var` for loading the offset (address) or else `mov al, [var1]` for loading the content of the address.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks from answering :) I checked it now again and using [] and not using them priveds the same outcome. I don't understand why that happens, since the data label is the *address* of the data itself. =[ One more Question: If the name of the variable is its address, why use OFFSET. I mean, the variable is the address, so the OFFSET directive is useless, isnt it?

Comment: Tradition, probably. In 32-bit, flat mode, offset and address are interchangeable but in segmented mode (e.g. 16-bit DOS) they are not.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I still don't understand why those two move instructions do the same. As I see it, the first mov instruction should not even compile since an address is 32 bit and al is only 8 bits... I also read that global variables addresses are allocated during assembly time. How can it be since every computer has different memory locations free, and others in use?

Comment: _"I still don't understand why those two move instructions do the same"_. Because MASM and TASM interpret `mov reg,[label]` and `mov reg,label` the same way (as if you had used brackets in both cases) - that's just way it is. NASM doesn't do this; in NASM syntax `mov reg,label` would load `reg` with the address of `label` (like `mov reg,offset label` in MASM/TASM syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MASM (and only there!) `mov al, var1` works with the **content** of `var1`. Using the name of the label "naked" is called "Direct Memory Operand". See [MS MASM 6.0 Programmer’s Guide (Scroll to section 3.2.3, "Direct Memory Operands")](https://www.pcjs.org/pubs/pc/reference/microsoft/mspl13/masm/mpguide/). If you need the address of that label you have to use the [`OFFSET`-Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/009k3eeh.aspx).

[The operator `[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7kxw03s9.aspx) has a special meaning. I adds the expression between the brackets to the expression before the brackets.

`mov al, [var1]`

is equivalent to

`mov al, 0[var1]`

is equivalent to

`mov al, 0 + var1`

is equivalent to

`mov al, var1 + 0`

is equivalent to

`mov al, var1`

You shouldn't use the []-operator in MASM, if you don't really need it, since it has some side effects.

Comment: Thanks for answering. for INdirect operands, I understand i should use the brackets though, right?

Comment: @NoamSolovechick: Yes, if the instruction would change its meaning w/o brackets (e.g. registers).

Comment: Can you give any examples of downsides of using `[var1]`?  Some people recommend *always* using `[]` for memory operands even in MASM syntax where you don't need them.