# Inderect jump in assembly on register or variable

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm, memory-segmentation

So I am trying to indirectly jump on a variable or register, but it works only when I initialize a variable in the data segment. What am I doing wrong?

```
.286
...
Data1 segment
address dd FUNC
Data1 ends

Code1 segment
ASSUME cs:Code1, ds:Data1
MAIN PROC
  mov AX,Data1
  mov DS,AX
  call address ; <- works

 ;mov address, FUNC <-- don't
 ;call address ;    <-- work

 ;mov ax, FUNC ;    <-- don't
 ;call ax      ;    <-- work

  mov AX,4C00H
  int 21H
MAIN ENDP
Code1 ends

Code2 segment
ASSUME cs:Code2, ds:Data1
COPY FUNC FAR
  ret
FUNC ENDP
Code2 ends
```

Comment: You're looking for the OFFSET keyword to put a label address into a register, instead of loading from it.  Also, obviously `call far ax` can't work because AX is only a 16-bit register but a new CS:IP would take 32 bits.  And a near call to a function that uses a far ret would leave a copy of CS on the stack.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call.

Comment: [Confused about pointers and values in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28073149) shows OFFSET syntax, but it's not an exact duplicate because this question also has problems with making a near `call ax` to a `far` function.  And of course `OFFSET` only gets the `off` part of `seg:off`, so that wouldn't be sufficient to store a 32-bit far-pointer.  Presumably there's some other keyword you'd need for the high half.  Of course without 386 for 32-bit immediates, you can only `mov [mem], imm16` in a single instruction, not a whole far pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks. But with ```mov OFFSET address``` I got a warning "Illegal size for operand". It does work fine while I have value initialized but does not otherwise. How I understand, OFFSET does not return code segment. How could I get it as well?

Comment: Yeah, read the 2nd part of my 2nd comment, about how `offset address` is only a 16-bit quantity, so you'd need `mov word ptr [address+0], OFFSET FUNC` to store the low half, and something else for the high half (the segment part of FUNC's full address). I don't know what, I don't know MASM very well.  It's much easier for a NEAR function, then you can just `mov ax, OFFSET FUNC` / `call ax`.  Segmentation is mostly pointless these days; if you want to write larger programs, write 32-bit or 64-bit code.

Comment: For the second version you want  `mov word ptr [address], offset FUNC`
 `mov word ptr [address+2], seg FUNC`
 `call address`

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks, that works great. Maybe, you also know how to make a far call with two 16 bit registers?

Comment: You can't do it directly. You could do `mov word ptr [address], offset FUNC`
 `mov word ptr [address+2], seg FUNC`
 `mov bx, offset address`
 `call dword ptr [bx]`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Wait, `call FUNC` wouldn't assemble to `call ptr16:16` because it's declared as a far proc?  Or do you mean for the general case of 2x 16-bit integer constants that aren't the seg:off of a "far" symbol the assembler knows about already?